# Работа с массивом C#

Tags: c#

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в коде. Суть ошибки такова, что значение переменной `y` постоянно больше размера массива (32), что в дальнейшем вызывает ошибку:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException.

```
        string msg, abc, key, enmsg;
        int n = 32; // количество символов в таблице
        char [,] tabl = new char[n,n];
        msg = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);  // получение сообщения
        key = Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text);  // получение ключа  
        abc = "абвгдеёжзиёклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";  // русский алфавит
        enmsg = Convert.ToString("0");
        // формирование таблицы
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    tabl[i, j] = abc[j];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
                {
                    tabl[i, j] = abc[j];
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    tabl[i, j] = abc[j];
                }
            }
        }

        int msgLen = Convert.ToInt32(msg.Length);   // длина сообщения
        int keyLen = Convert.ToInt32(key.Length);   // длина ключа

        int k = 0;
        int t = 0;
        int p = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        while(true)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (msg[t] == tabl[0, j])
                {
                    y = tabl[0, j];
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (key[p] == tabl[i, 0])
                {
                    x = tabl[i, 0];
                }
            }

            if (k == 0)
            {
                enmsg = Convert.ToString(tabl[x, y]);
            }
            else
            {
                enmsg = enmsg + Convert.ToString(tabl[x, y]);
            }

            k++;
            if (k == msgLen) break;
            if (p > keyLen) p = 0;
        }
        textBox3.Text = enmsg;    // вывод результата
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас в строке с алфавитом 2 буквы Ё, но это не главное.

Во-вторых, в массиве tabl у вас получаются все коды в таком виде: `'a' 1072, 'b' 1073` и т.д. В момент, когда программа обращается к переменной `y`, в ней находится число, которое больше или равно 1072, а массив ограничен всего 32.

Comment: а как 2ую ошибку можно исправить?

Comment: Я заменял `tabl[x, y]` на `tabl[x, y-1072]`. Это самый простой костыль. Эксепшн исчезает, но результат кодирования какой-то странный, но тут уже надо  менять реализацию алгоритма.

Comment: а сама таблица правильно составлена?
просто получается я вставил "y-1072" и у меня при шифровании все заменяет одинаковыми символами, а также есть варианты, когда y > 1072

Comment: Ой, простите за глупость. Нашел уже ошибку. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

abc = "абвгдеёжзиёклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя".length == 33